# Android Alpha testing

Tags: android, testing

I have been having issues downloading the latest version of my app as part of Alpha testing. I have uploaded 6 versions and every time i download the app i just get the first version.

Thinking this is something to do with cache, on few versions, i waited more then 24 hrs for the download. Even this did not help.

Is there anything that i can do to make sure that i download the latest version. All the previous versions are archived and only the latest version is published/active

Thanks for your help
RD

Answer (score 0):

You can completely uninstall the application but keep user data and then you can reinstall the application. This will mean all the files saved will remain there but then the application files will be 'updated' by you deleting them then reinstalling the application.

Comment: I have uninstalled the application from the Android device(nexus) several times. the problem is the version is not getting updated on the Google play centre

Comment: Well then that would believe me to think that something is either going wrong where you are uploading the wrong file or it is something to do with the manifest. It is hard to tell from the information provided